# 64-bit Scintilla-like text-editing component?

Tags: windows, 64-bit, text-editor, scintilla

Is there a 64-bit-compatible alternative to [Scintilla](http://www.scintilla.org/) out there that's open-source?

Comment: What do you mean by '64-bit compatible'? Scintilla can be compiled as a 64-bit build. While you'll probably get some warnings, it will compile and work.

Comment: @pezcode: It won't work for file sizes > 4 GB, and it's really risky with > 2 GB. A 64-bit compatible one would work with such sizes.

Answer (score 1):

These are all .NET components:

ScintillaNET

Based on Scintilla, and has a 64-bit version of the lexer DLL.

http://scintillanet.codeplex.com/

http://scintillanet.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=FAQ&referringTitle=Documentation#FAQ-64-bit

AvalonEdit (editing component used in SharpDevelop)

http://channel9.msdn.com/coding4fun/blog/Creating-your-own-Text-Editor-with-AvalonEdit

ICSharpCode.TextEditor (precursor to AvalonEdit; used in prior Windows Forms-based SharpDevelop)

https://github.com/icsharpcode/SharpDevelop/wiki/Using-the-texteditor